# How to Covert Google analtics API response to Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

I have some code which exports data from Google analytics using the Google Analtics data api.

```
def sample_run_report(credentials=None, property_id="YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID"):
"""Runs a simple report on a Google Analytics 4 property."""

client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient(credentials=credentials)
dates = [DateRange(start_date="7daysAgo", end_date='today')]
metrics = [Metric(name='activeUsers')]
dimensions = [], #[Dimension(name='city')]
request = RunReportRequest(
    property=f'properties/{property_id}',
    metrics=metrics,
    date_ranges=dates,
)

response = client.run_report(request)
print(response)
```

This code works file it exports the data in the standard response for the api.

```
{
  "dimensionHeaders": [
    {
      object (DimensionHeader)
    }
  ],
  "metricHeaders": [
    {
      object (MetricHeader)
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      object (Row)
    }
  ]
 .....
}
```

I would like to format this as a pandas [dataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) I have not been able to find any method to output it as a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/RunReportResponse) only exports data in a single format.  I was able to create a method which will covert the response into a [Pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

```
def covert_to_pandas(data):

    # Grab all the columns in the result
    columns = []
    for col in data.dimension_headers:
        columns.append(col.name)
    for col in data.metric_headers:
        columns.append(col.name)

    # Grab all the rows in the result.
    rows = []
    for row_data in data.rows:
        row = []
        for val in row_data.dimension_values:
            row.append(val.value)
        for val in row_data.metric_values:
            row.append(val.value)
        rows.append(row)

    # convert to data frame
    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
```

Note

If you want to use this with any of the graphs make sure to add the following.

```
df = df.astype(float)
```

or you will get an error

> raise TypeError("no numeric data to plot") TypeError: no numeric data to plot

This is due to the type being object.

Now I can use it

[image]

[Examining Google Analytics GA4 Data with Python and Pandas.](https://www.daimto.com/examining-google-analytics-ga4-data-with-python-and-pandas/)